# Access JTextArea text of Parent JDialog from another JDialog

Tags: java, jdialog

I have two `JDialog`. First one is main one named `MainJDialog`. Second one is child one named `ChildJDialog`. And i have `JButton` in `MainJDialog` which get `ChildJDialog` to screen when pressed like this;

```
ChildJDialog childJDialog;
childJDialog = new ChildJDialog (MainJDialog.this, true);
childJDialog.setVisible(true);
```

Also i have several `JTextArea` in `MainJDialog` filled with user entered informations.

I have added `JButton` to `ChildJDialog` and want access of spesific `JTextArea` text of currently running owner `MainJDialog` when pressed.

```
private void getTextOfJTextArea1ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                                    
    System.out.println(ChildJDialog.this.getOwner().getClass());       
}
```

Result:

```
class tryingproject.MainJDialog
```

Above `ActionEvent` gives me true owner `JDialog` but i dont know how can access its components.

Any helps appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `but i dont know how can access its components.` - Well the same way the child dalog class has a "getter" method to get the parent dialog, iff you want to access a component in the MainJDialog class then you need to create a "getter" method. Maybe something like `getTextComponent()`?

Comment: I can't instantie `MainJDialog` in `ChildJDialog` because user enter some information to `JTextArea1` in `MainJDialog` than press button for call the `ChildJDialog`. When `ChildJDialog` coming to screen `MainJDialog` still there with filled information. I want access these components for get the user entered text.

Comment: I know i can create constructor for pass the desired information to `ChildJdialog` but i dont want pass directly. I want reach them when user press the button in `ChildJDialog` dinamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**--- SOLVED ---**

I create a constructor in `ChildJDialog` and pass the JTextArea1 text of `MainJDialog` as parameter to the `ChildJDialog` when user call the `ChildJDialog` just like below;

```
ChildJDialog childJDialog;
childJDialog = new ChildJDialog (MainJDialog.this, true, textOfJTextArea1);
childJDialog.setVisible(true);
```

And i use this text anywhere in `ChildJDialog`

Not the exact solution i know but working for now.